"Flair" x "Phlegm". Do they have the same meaning here?
Do the expressions "flair" and "phlegm" have the same meaning in this type of text?
I agree that he is much older than her and that she has never been interested in older men before, and believe me, I really have no plausible explanation for this huge attraction she claims to feel for him. Maybe she is simply impressed by his Cary Grant flair / phlegm.
Here's what I have found in the researches I did before asking:
Definições de Oxford Languages phlegm /flem/ noun noun: phlegm the thick viscous substance secreted by the mucous membranes of the respiratory passages, especially when produced in excessive or abnormal quantities, e.g., when someone is suffering from a cold. Semelhantes: mucus catarrh mucous secretion (in medieval science and medicine) one of the four bodily humors, believed to be associated with a calm, stolid, or apathetic temperament. calmness of temperament.
"phlegm and determination carried them through many difficult situations" self-control / calmness / calm / coolness / composure / sangfroid / level-headedness / equanimity / serenity / tranquility / placidity / placidness / impassivity / self-possession / self-confidence / self-assurance / stolidity / stolidness / imperturbability / impassiveness / dispassionateness / cool / unflappability.

I don't get the question. Even phlegmatic has a different meaning, so I suppose the older man has both flair and phlegm.

Try using a dictionary.

I’m voting to close this question because this can be answered by dictionary. Phlegm is the mucus that you cough up when you have a cold, nothing to with "flair"....  The quoted text needs a source too.

@Lambie: I did. If one of them's yours, will you retract your downvote / closevote?

Thanks, everyone. Here's what I have found in the researches I did before asking: Definições de Oxford Languages
phlegm
/flem/
noun
noun: phlegm
the thick viscous substance secreted by the mucous membranes of the respiratory passages, especially when produced in excessive or abnormal quantities, e.g., when someone is suffering from a cold.
Semelhantes:
mucus
catarrh
mucous secretion
(in medieval science and medicine) one of the four bodily humors, believed to be associated with a calm, stolid, or apathetic temperament.
calmness of temperament.

"phlegm and determination carried them through many difficult situations"
self-control / calmness / calm / coolness / composure / sangfroid / level-headedness / equanimity / serenity / tranquility / placidity / placidness / impassivity / self-possession / self-confidence / self-assurance / stolidity / stolidness / imperturbability / impassiveness / dispassionateness / cool / unflappability

Hi, James. The quoted text was created my me.

@Itamar Add those definitions to the question please.

Hi, Laurel. Thanks, I'll do that.

@FumbleFingers - the word 'phlegm' shares some properties with 'spunk', doesn't it?

I mean it is a personal attribute (a kind of brave determination)!

@JamesK - As Itamar says, phlegm also has a metaphorical meaning based on the ancient theory of the four humours - hence the adjectives phlegmatic, sanguine, choleric, melancholic. But I agree that it's nothing to do with 'flair'.

[correction: found when doing research on the probleem]. In any case, the word phlegm make no sense in that sentence.

@KateBunting Yes, but metaphorical meanings require being used sensibly {both meanings}.

Apart from mucus and some obsolete / historical definitions, the full OED has this definition for phlegm...

Phlegmatic disposition; absence of excitability or enthusiasm; calmness, imperturbability, self-possession, evenness of temper; (also, in negative sense) dullness, sluggishness, stolidness, apathy. See phlegmatic adj.

Cary Grant was perceived as "debonair" (having "flair", stylishly elegant) both in real life and in the characters he portrayed. And of course, his most well-known line is...

Frankly my dear, I don't give a damn! 1

So although both words can reasonably be applied to Cary Grant (and thus by extension, to someone else), they're not really synonymous. They refer to different (but potentially overlapping) aspects of Grant's persona.

These are the "synonyms" Google returned me for flair...

stylishness, originality

... with these listed as "similar"...

style, panache, verve, dash, elan, finesse, poise, elegance, sparkle, brio, inventiveness, creativity, taste

(poise implies evenness of temper, imperturbability)

1  OK, that's Clark Gable, not Cary Grant. But if I confused them, someone else (the cited writer or target audience) might do the same. And Grant was pretty "laid-back, unflappable". One of his recorded quotes is...

“My formula for living is quite simple. I get up in the morning and I go to bed at night. In between, I occupy myself as best I can.”


"Frankly my dear, I don't give a damn" It's Clark Gabel, Gone with the Wind???

Oh. I should have checked. Well, I'm sure Cary Grant had some suitable line... Apparently his most famous (real-life) line is "Everyone wants to be Cary Grant, even I want to be Cary Grant"

The Hollywood Greats are forgotten, no one watches black and white movies any more unless they're majoring in film. North by Northwest and How to Catch a Thief are probably the two films in which CG was his "coolest".

It wasn't easy to even find any memorable lines from the characters CG portrayed. Maybe that's the same for most actors, I never tried looking before. But back then all the top male actors were "heartthrob movie stars", and many of them would have similar qualities of "even-temperedness" and "flair".

Actually, it depends very much which specific actor, for getting real-life or "movieland" quotes. Google is falling over itself to tell me the top 10 lines delivered by Clint Eastwood characters.      1 "You've gotta ask yourself one question: 'Do I feel lucky?
2 "Go ahead, make my day." ...
3 "You see, in this world, there are two kinds of people, my friend: those with loaded guns and those who dig." ...
4 "Get three coffins ready. ...

Some quotes from Cary Grant - in addition to those already mentioned here: I pretended to be somebody I wanted to be until finally I became that person. Or he became me. / Insanity runs in my family. It practically gallops. / To succeed with the opposite sex, tell her you're impotent. She can't wait to disprove it. / Ah, beware of snobbery; it is the unwelcome recognition of one's own past failings. / Divorce is a game played by lawyers. / I think that making love is the best form of exercise. / When people tell you how young you look, they are telling you how old you are.

"Frankly, my dear, I'm phlegmatic" was in the original script.

@TimR: I'd like to believe that! (But I don't :)

phlegmatix [noun] sure. phlegm not.
